# Iterating over related records in visualforce using standard controller

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

I'm diving into visualforce and the standard controller for the first time and having trouble iterating over a single opportunity's related records. The below code produces an error:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<apex:pageBlock title="{!Opportunity.name}">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!Opportunity.Id}">
        <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.Custom_object__c}" var="c">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                {!c.Name}
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock></apex:page>
```

The error I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Error: Unknown property 'String.Name'
```

I take from this that the Visualforce is not interpreting the `{!c.Name}` as the array of objects I thought it was but instead as a string. I am able to save the file when I remove `{!c.Name}` which makes me think that  is correct but, on the other hand, when substituting `value="{!Opportunity.Account}"` the code correctly retrieves the related Account. My instinct is that I'm not referencing the related child-objects correctly. I've been banging my head for a bit of time and was wondering if someone could provide some insight as to what is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your instincts seem right. The field `Opportunity.Custom_object__c` almost certainly contains the Id of a single custom object (unless it is a text field rather than a reference field). As such, the apex:repeat only has a string in var `c`.

Instead you will need to find the name of the relationship from Opportunity to your custom object. This would be the parent-to-child relationship name if you expect to have multiple items in the repeater.

[Understanding Relationship Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm) can be helpful here. If you look at the [Mother Daughter example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#i1422263) the relationship name you would want would be Daughters__r. Note the `__r` suffix for the relationship.

[image]

Once you have the correct relationship name, you might find the [apex:relatedList](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) control useful.

Comment: Hi Daniel (nice name) I see your answer now more fully explains the issue so I've selected your answer.

Comment: Glad to help. I was going to suggest using the Schema Builder to display the relationship, but it doesn't show the relationship names.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Relation API Name and not the SObject API Name
I edited your code so you can test it with Account and Contacts

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:pageBlock title="{!Account.name}">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!Account.Id}">
        <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="c">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                {!c.Name}
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock></apex:page>
```

You could find the relation name in the Lookup/Master-Deatil field definition.

Comment: It took me a bit more fiddling but as you said, I replaced the API name with Child Relationship Name followed by __r and it worked a charm. Thanks for your help!